# Google Drive API downloadUrl does not work

Tags: google-drive-api

- I have some audio recordings on Google Drive
- the files are "viewable by anyone with the link"
- I have created a podcast feed that links to these files

In order for a podcast client to download the files, it needs a direct download link. The Google Drive API returns two fields in a file's metadata that can play this role:

- `webContentLink` is intended to be used in a browser. It allows my podcast client to download files less than 25MB; unfortunately, over this amount Google requires user confirmation since the file is not virus-scanned. This user-confirmation step prevents my podcast clients from downloading the file if it is over 25MB.
- `downloadUrl` is what you're supposed to use, but I cannot get it to work at all. If I copy-paste a `downloadUrl` directly into my browser's address bar, I get nothing. Similarly my podcast client can't download anything with a downloadUrl.

[This issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6632) seems unresolved and suggests this is still broken, but I have a few questions:

- should I need to submit an API key with the downloadUrl request? No key is needed for webContentLink.
- is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: For `downloadUrl`, you cannot access the contents in a browser. Try testing if you are able to get the contents with the `downloadUrl` using [Oauth 2.0 Playground][1] and see if you can see the contents of the file.


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: I have the same issue. Impossible to download a file from Google Drive with Apis if the file is over 25 MB.

Have you found a workaround ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When requesting the file with the downloadUrl you must specify the following authorization in your request header:

```
"Authorization: Bearer $token"
```

Where $token is the access_token returned by `gapi` for the user like this:

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;
```

So if you were using curl the request would be something like this:

```
curl -o download -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" $downloadUrl
```